# SQL server Encryption

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL- Encryption Database](https://serverfault.com/questions/259354/sql-encryption-database)

I have taken backup from the live environment and trying to use it on the local box. The database in the live is encrypted with a key.

I have restored the database to localbox and cannot run any stored procedures as I have the following issue:

```
Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.
```

Has anybody faced this issue, and how did you manage to solve?  Could you provide the answer step by step?

I know the password for the encryption on the live DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
open master key decryption by password = '<your password>'
alter master key add encryption by service master key
```